# Email download gets missing file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some code that runs every week using Whenever gem. It creates a file and sends a download link.

ApplicationMailer

```
  def weekly_email
    file = CSVData::Report.new(time).create_csv
    @filename = File.basename(file.path)
    mail(
      :from => "from",
      :to => "to",
      :subject => "Data #{time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")}"
    )
  end
```

The file is stored in `downloads/`. The issue is, it works in testing, it works sometimes, but sometimes it generate a Missing File error:

Error:

```
ActionController::MissingFile occurred in file_downloads#download:
Cannot read file downloads/data_9_17_2015.csv
  actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/data_streaming.rb:71:in `send_file'
```

Here is the download code:

```
def download
    send_file "downloads/#{params[:filename]}.csv", type: "application/csv", x_sendfile: true 
end
```

Here is a shortened version of the file creation:

```
def create_file
  file_data = some_cool_data
  file = create_file(File.join(Dir.pwd, "/downloads/#{@file_name}.csv"))
  file.write(file_data)
  file.close
  file
end

def create_file(path)
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(path))
  File.new(path, "w+")
end
```

I dont think its an issue with the file reference (i.e. `/dowloads` vs `downloads`), because it works fine in testing and sometimes in production. It just seems that the file is getting deleted. What could be causing the missing file error?

Comment: Maybe `download` called twice?

Comment: @dimakura What do you mean called twice? It shouldn't matter if it gets called twice. ```send_file``` does not delete the file.

Comment: Doesn't it overwrites previous file? The file name seems the same. Isn't it better to use tempfiles for this and also use block instead of open/close operations?

Comment: @dimakura Send file just sends the file to the user it doesn't upload or create any new data.  Why would it overwrite the file? I don't want to use Tempfile because the file may not be downloaded immediately. May a block would be better than open/close, but I think that part is irrelevant to this error.

Comment: Maybe `Rails.root` instead of `Dir.pwd`.

Comment: @dimakura Sorry, I still down understand how that would cause it to overwrite the file.